# Как импортировать jquery в модули

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, сборка

При сборке проекта с помощью webpack встал вопрос. Как импортировать jquery в нужные модули.

Я могу это сделать глобально с помощью webpack.ProvidePlugin, согласно [инструкции](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#plugin-provideplugin) из документации webpack:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    }),
],
resolve: {
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extension: ['', '.js', '.styl']
},
```

Но как это сделать явно для нужных модулей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы это сделал, используя возможности es6, например вот-так:

```
import $ from 'pathOfJquery'
```

Это в свою очередь требует использование babel-polyfill в webpack, вот так:

```
 module: {
    loaders: [{
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
      ],
      test: /\.js$/,
      .....
```

и пресет для бабеля .babelrc

```
{
"presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Вероятно, есть еще какие-нибудь менее громоздкие способы.

Comment: спасибо! попробую